# Converting a structured text file but of non standard structure to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to learn basic data I/o and preprocessing. I have a text file of the format given below. It is a non standard format (unlike CSV,JSON etc) I need to convert the following structure into a table like format (more precisely a dataframe that we obtain from csv files)

**Input**

```
product/productId: B000H13270
review/userId: A3J6I70Z9Q0HRX
review/profileName: Lindey H. Magee
review/helpfulness: 1/3
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1261785600
review/summary: it's fabulous, but *not* from amazon!
review/text: the price on this product certainly raises my attention on compairing amazon price with the local stores. i can get a can of this rotel at my local kroger for $1. dissapointing!

product/productId: B000H13270
review/userId: A1YLOZQKBX3J1S
review/profileName: R. Lee Dailey "Lee_Dailey"
review/helpfulness: 1/4
review/score: 3.0
review/time: 1221177600
review/summary: too expensive
review/text: howdy y'all,<br /><br />the actual product is VERY good - i'd rate the item a 4 on it's own. however, it's only ONE dollar at the local grocery and - @ twenty eight+ dollars per twelve pack - these are running almost two and a half dollars each.<br /><br />as i said, TOO EXPENSIVE. [*sigh ...*] i was really hoping to get them at something approaching the local cost.<br /><br />take care,<br />lee
```

**Output**

```
product/productId | review/UserId ......... | review/text
B000H13270        |A3J6I70Z9Q0HRX           |  the price on this .... dissapointing!
B000H13270       | A1YLOZQKBX3J1S          |howdy y'all,<br /> ..... lee
```

In `Python` I could have performed the same in the following manner

```
dataFile = open('filename').read().split('\n') # obtain each data chunk
revDict = dict()
for item in dataFile:
    stuff = item.split(':')
    revDict[stuff[0]].append(stuff[1])
```

How something similar can be achieved in `R`. Are there any equivalents in `R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way that splits on colons (all colons except the first on each line are removed from the file) then reshapes the data from long to wide:

```
mytxt <- readLines(file("mytext.txt"))
mytable <- read.table(text=gsub("^([^:]*:)|:", "\\1", mytxt), sep = ":", quote = "")
mytable$id <- rep(1:(nrow(mytable)/8), each = 8)
res <- reshape(mytable, direction = "wide", timevar = "V1", idvar = "id")
```

Which gives:

```
  id V2.product/productId V2.review/userId           V2.review/profileName  V2.review/helpfulness V2.review/score V2.review/time                      V2.review/summary                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    V2.review/text
1  1           B000H13270   A3J6I70Z9Q0HRX                 Lindey H. Magee                   1/3             5.0     1261785600  it's fabulous, but *not* from amazon!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                the price on this product certainly raises my attention on compairing amazon price with the local stores. i can get a can of this rotel at my local kroger for $1. dissapointing!
9  2           B000H13270   A1YLOZQKBX3J1S  R. Lee Dailey \\"Lee_Dailey\\"                   1/4             3.0     1221177600                          too expensive  howdy y'all,<br /><br />the actual product is VERY good - i'd rate the item a 4 on it's own. however, it's only ONE dollar at the local grocery and - @ twenty eight+ dollars per twelve pack - these are running almost two and a half dollars each.<br /><br />as i said, TOO EXPENSIVE. [*sigh ...*] i was really hoping to get them at something approaching the local cost.<br /><br />take care,<br />lee
```

Assumes that each case consists of 8 lines.

Comment: The assumption that each case has 8 lines is a valid assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing this. Here's how I would do it, using `readLines`, `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
con <- file("mytxt.txt", "r", blocking = FALSE)
z <- readLines(con)
z <- as.data.frame(z) %>% separate(z, into = c("datatype", "val"), sep=": ") %>%
         mutate(rep = cumsum(datatype=="product/productId")) %>% 
         na.omit() %>%
         spread(datatype, val)
```

You'll get an output in a dataframe like:

```
  rep product/productId review/helpfulness         review/profileName review/score
1   1        B000H13270                1/3            Lindey H. Magee          5.0
2   2        B000H13270                1/4 R. Lee Dailey "Lee_Dailey"          3.0
                         review/summary
1 it's fabulous, but *not* from amazon!
2                         too expensive
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      review/text
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                               the price on this product certainly raises my attention on compairing amazon price with the local stores. i can get a can of this rotel at my local kroger for $1. dissapointing!
2 howdy y'all,<br /><br />the actual product is VERY good - i'd rate the item a 4 on it's own. however, it's only ONE dollar at the local grocery and - @ twenty eight+ dollars per twelve pack - these are running almost two and a half dollars each.<br /><br />as i said, TOO EXPENSIVE. [*sigh ...*] i was really hoping to get them at something approaching the local cost.<br /><br />take care,<br />lee
  review/time  review/userId
1  1261785600 A3J6I70Z9Q0HRX
2  1221177600 A1YLOZQKBX3J1S
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 'poor man' method.

I assume that all blocks of data has the same fields, there is no missing fields, and `:` is use only as separator.

You have 8 fields, in the example I use 3 and simplify its names.

```
fields <- 3

# you can use file="example.txt" instead text=...
data <- read.table(text="
    prod: foo  1 
    rev1: bar 11
    rev2: bar 12

    prod: foo  2
    rev1: bar 21
    rev2: bar 22
  ", sep=":", strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

rows <- dim(data)[1]/fields

mdata <- matrix(data$V2, nrow=rows, ncol=fields, byrow=TRUE)

colnames(mdata) <- data$V1[1:fields]

as.data.frame(mdata)
```

Result:

```
     prod    rev1    rev2
1  foo  1  bar 11  bar 12
2  foo  2  bar 21  bar 22
```